# "do while" loop hangs, does not repeat

Tags: c++, do-while

I've been having an issue with a do while loop not repeating.
When I choose N when prompted to add two numbers again, it exits the program as intended, but choosing Y or y hangs the program, taking me to the next line, but rendering me unable to type anything. I would appreciate it if you could assist me. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int number1, number2; //Two numbers
int sum;              //Sum
char again;     //For yet another attempt


{  //Inputting the two numbers

    cout << "\nEnter two numbers, and i will add them: ";
    cin >> number1 >> number2;

    //Adding the two numbers

    sum = number1 + number2;
    cout << "The sum of the two numbers you have picked is " << sum << "\n\n";

    //Does the user want to add two other numbers?
    cout << "Do you want to add two other numbers? (Y/N) ";
    cin >> again;
}
    while (again == ('y') || again == ('Y'));


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should the code block (for looping) be after the `while` keyword, not before?

Comment: That’s for a normal while statement. I simply forgot the do part.

Comment: Syntax needs to be followed while coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do { statement} while(condition)
```

do while loop syntax is above, I guess you missed do world in you syntax.
   try replacing you do-while block like below.

```
do{  //Inputting the two numbers

cout << "\nEnter two numbers, and i will add them: ";
cin >> number1 >> number2;

//Adding the two numbers

sum = number1 + number2;
cout << "The sum of the two numbers you have picked is " << sum << "\n\n";

//Does the user want to add two other numbers?
cout << "Do you want to add two other numbers? (Y/N) ";
cin >> again;}while (again == ('y') || again == ('Y'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm honestly surprised I missed that!

Comment: Sorry, I’m new. Is it the Answer Your Question button?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: To accept the answer, do I press the Answer Your Question button?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Welcome! No problem

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you need a Do in a Do While. Can't say it any better than lion_pankaj.

Also build check each time you add something new to code or debug before running program and check all warnings or errors if any. Also depend on IDE used to help find little errors. We all forget little stuff at times.